# General version of Cauchy-Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to know if, given a continuous function $h$, the equation $f'(x) = 1+\int_0^x f(t) h(x-t)$ has a solution $f$ in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Intuitively, it appears we can always recursively infinitesimaly construct such an $f$ since it only depends on the past values, and i know the real formalisation of this kind of ideas is the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem.
However, i could not see any trick that would make this turn into an ordinary differential equation with only $f$ and its derivatives.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f=0$ is a solution, but probably not the one you want. Do you have any initial conditions?

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing it out. I have edited the post

Comment: What is your equation? Is it $f'(x) = \int_0^x [f(t) h(x-t) + 1]dt$ or $f'(x) = \int_0^x f(t) h(x-t) dt+ 1$? It is misleading.

Comment: I have fixed it, although i think if there existed a solution it would exist for both of them anyway.